# Replace command in Bash script from another script

Tags: bash, sed, variable-substitution

I'm trying to setup a script that will fetch changes from github where a script has a command that's not executable in Mac OS X.
What I'm aiming for is to use `sed` etc to replace the command within that script.

These are the commands:

Original command (to be replaced in script):

```
DIR=$(dirname "$(readlink -f $0)")
```

New command (I want to replace with):

```
DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd -P)"
```

What I've tried so far:

```
StartStopScript="/path/to/script.sh"

DIRnew=""$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd -P)""

DIRold=""$(dirname "$(readlink -f $0)")""

echo "$StartStopScript" | sed -e 's/"$DIRold"/"$DIRnew"/g'
```

This fails and the commands seems to be executed instead of interpreted as a string.
Figure it comes down to quoting in `sed`.

Grateful for any help I can get with this.

Comment: should `$OrigScript` == `$StartStopScript`?

Comment: I would strongly advice to use an `if` loop defining the OS in the script as in `if [ OS = Mac ] ; then cmd=MacCommand ; else cmd=LinuxCommand ; fi`. Replacing a string from a variable with `sed`'s special characters like `&` in them is a mess, as you would have to escape them while defining the variable in the first place (e.g. `DIRnew='"$(... \&\& pwd -P )"'`)

Comment: @Fiximan:Correct OrigScript and StartstopScript should be the same. I've edit my post accordingly.  No need to have an OS check since this script will only be run on Mac's, since the original script works out of the box on Linux.

Comment: You are using "/" as separator in sed, but your content also contains some '/'. replace the sed with : `sed -e "s,${DIRold},${DIRnew},g"`

Answer (score 0):

```
OrigScript="/path/to/script.sh"
echo $OrigScript
/path/to/script.sh
#note: no quotes
OrigScript='"/path/to/script.sh"'
echo $OrigScript
"/path/to/script.sh"
#note: with quotes, but not good for filesnames, rather use "$filename" in the command argument


DIRnew='"$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" \&\& pwd -P)"'
echo $DIRnew
"$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" \&\& pwd -P)"
#note: with quotes, escaping & needed for suppressing interpretation by sed

DIRold='"$(dirname "$(readlink -f $0)")"'
echo $DIRold
"$(dirname "$(readlink -f $0)")"
#note: in your question the original DIR=.. did NOT have double quotes,
#I assume a typo

sed -e "s/$DIRold/$DIRnew/g" "$OrigScript"
#note: $OrigScript should NOT have the double quotes in it!
#note: I assume $OrigScript == $StartStopScript

#test:
echo $DIRold | sed "s/$DIRold/$DIRnew/"
"$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd -P)"
#result includes double quotes!
```

1) for declaring a variable with (double) quotes, you need to escape the quotes to have the quotes in the string, better use single quotes to make sure the string inside is exactly just the string and no variables are interpreted. This also simplifies the use of `&`, and `$()` as the are then not interpreted by the shell

2) for `echo`ing (double) quotes, escape them

3) for allowing `sed` to interpret a shell variable, you MUST use double quotes around the `sed` command ( with single quotes, the command `sed 's/$a/$b/'` will try to replace the actual string '$a' with the string '$b' , also be aware of the special meaning of `$` in `sed`), double quotes around the variable within the `sed` command is not needed, as `sed` is for treating strings with any character (with restrictions regarding the special command characters of `sed`).

4) `echo "$StartStopScript" | sed -e 's/"$DIRold"/"$DIRnew"/g'` will echo the variable `$StartStopScript` ( which I assume is simply the file name of the script ) and try to replace the variables in that string (i.e. the file name). For applying `sed` to a file, use `sed 's/a/b/g' file` (output written to `stout`), for overwriting the file, use `-i` (use with care, i.e. test for the right substitutions first)

5) `&` has a special meaning in `sed`, it reprints the initial (matching) pattern:

```
echo ABC | sed 's/A/&12/'
A12BC
```

You will have to escape it in the replacement pattern to suppress interpretation:

```
echo ABC | sed 's/A/\&12/'
&12BC
```

Thus the variable `$DIRnew` needs to have the escape backslashes in its string.

6) Apart from that, I would suggest to rather use an `if` loop identifying the OS and to adapt the commands accordingly. That way you only need one script for both OSes. I.e.

```
if [ OS = Mac ] ; then
    dir=MacDir
else
    dir=LinuxDir
fi
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful post and walkthrough of each section of the script. Needed to make some smaller adjustments to get it running under OS X (sed -i '.bak') since sed was trowing up errors (undefined label).